# Place an image in a button using CSS responsive fluid design

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems in a specific part of a responsive fluid page I'm trying to build for tablet dimensions for now with 960px converted to 96% container's size.

To see what's the problem, it's available here: http://shopper.izigo.pt/vote/

The arrows figure image in the button is not fluid as the rest of all elements and if I try to change to portrait's orientation, the arrow gets to small. I have made the calculation based on target % context but in this particular case it's not working (here is the code):

css:

```
main form button img {
    float: right;
    width: 12.3943661971831%;           /* 44px current element size % 355px parent (button) size */
    margin-right: 2.8169014084507%;     /* 10px current element size % 355px parent (button) size  */
    margin-top: 3.09859154929577%;      /* 11px current element size % 355px parent (button) size  */
}
```

And the footer is not centered (here is the code):

css:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    width: 96%;     /* equal to the containers width because it's in a absolute position */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `img` inside your button is actually styling, and not content. Therefore it belongs in your css as a background image, and not in your html as a `img`. This also makes the positioning a lot easier:

```
main form button {
    background: url(path/to/image.png) no-repeat right center;
    padding-right: 20px; /* width of image to prevent the label from laying on top of it */
}
```

*(May I suggest you add a class to that button and target it that way, in stead of those long, hard to maintain, and slower selectors you use now)*

For the footer, in stead of defining a width you can just set the right and left property to 0 (when it is positioned absolute that is). this way it will take over the width of the parent. Something like this:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Both should work fine in your fluid design...

Comment: Hi thanks, but your solution don't make the image in the button fluid, so the size is always the same. I also lose the black BG color. Is it possible do make it fluid? Regarding the footer, great it's working! What do you mean by "long, hard to maintain, and slower selectors you use now"?